# Windows 8.1 RDP session too big

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 installed as UserA which runs in console but I connect mainly with UserB through RDP.

UserA has the setting "smaller" as DPI size, userB I cannot adjust because it is in RDP.

Result is a desktop with massive icons and enormous windows which make it hard to with with:

[image]

How can I get my desktop icons smaller?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, huge desktop contents, even though Icons are set to Small. This helps somewhat to get a smaller session window maximized but the contents is still huge.

http://llemarie.wordpress.com/2007/11/01/tip-scaling-your-remote-desktop-session/

Ahh, here is also a soultion for the oversized contents:

http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/blue-automatic-desktop-display-scaling

Apparently RDP defaults to 125% desktop scaling, setting it back to 100% makes it perfect!